# user role on UI-STATE

Tags: angularjs

in my app i have many different USER ROLE's. 
And on one state i need to set different roles. Bellow code, with only one user role, working ok

```
.state('distributor-dashboard', {
                url: '/distributor-dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'assets/html_templates/distributor-dashboard/distributor-dashboard.html',
                controller: 'distributorDashboardCtrl',
                authentication: {role: admin}
            })
```

But, if i try to add another roles, they don' work here is example

```
.state('distributor-dashboard', {
                url: '/distributor-dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'assets/html_templates/distributor-dashboard/distributor-dashboard.html',
                controller: 'distributorDashboardCtrl',
                authentication: {role: ["admin" || "user"]}
            })
```

Here is where i check USER ROLE

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {


    $rootScope.previousState = fromState.name;
    var auth = authService.authentication.isAuth;
     if (toState.name !== "login" && toState.name !== "signup" && toState.name !== "resset-password" && toState.name !== "new-password"  && toState.name !== "account-activation" && auth === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login',  {});
    } 

    var role = authService.authentication.role;

    if (toState.authentication !== undefined && toState.authentication.role !== role)  {
       event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login', {});
    }


}
```

Thnx.

Comment: in your second code, you are returning `array`, make sure the same is returned from service, or change, 
`authentication: {role: ("admin" != undefined ? "admin" : "user")}`

Comment: thnx, but this don't working...

Comment: getting any error?, just `console.log(toState.authentication)` and check what is cming

Comment: there is no error... just don't want to open state. I found solution, thnx

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It is necessary to set on STATE under authentification any role that we want to use.

```
authentication: {roles: ["admin", "user"]}
```

and then make a check if the roll there is in the allowed rolls

```
var userRole = authService.authentication.role;

    if (toState.authentication !== undefined && toState.authentication.roles.indexOf(userRole) < 0)  {
       event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login', {});
    }
```

I use indexOf for check, is roles in array. If someone have any question, feel free to ask

Comment: yes that's why I said, you are storing array there.

Comment: yes, thnx, you help me with suggestion. But im new one, and i can not give any VOTE UP for now

Comment: no problem, I haven't added an answer. anyway you got your solution.